# Simple USB button using C#

Tags: c#, usb

I want to do some playing around with reading out signals from pheriperals. I want to do the following:

In the past I had an internship at a small IT company, the had a broken LPT cable, they cut it open and used two cables to attach a button, they also had a piece of software to do something if the button was pressed.

Now I want to do the same using a broken USB cable and see if the D+ and D- are touching each other, if they are I want my software to do something. Is there a library that lets me check if two are touching? (don't now if I have to use the 5v and grnd or d+ and d-) or is it not possible using USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D+ and D- is a [differential pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling). You cannot just short them and capture that with PC.

To implement USB button, you will need to read button state with some microcontroller, like AT90USB162, and send data about button state to PC. One easy way is to configure microcontroller to work as a virtual serial port (see [LUFA project](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php)). This way you can read data from microcontroller the same way as from real serial port (see [SerialPort class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)).