# Detect USB button press

Tags: python, usb

I have a USB cable with the a button connecting the `+5V` and `DATA-` wires like this:

[image: USB diagram with button connecting <code>+5V</code> and <code>DATA-</code> wires]

When I plug the USB into my computer and press the button, it seemingly does nothing. Connecting an LED from the `DATA+` to `GND` wires shows a single brief flash in response to the button press.

Is it possible to detect the button press using Python?

Edit: I ran this script while holding the button down, and it outputted `b''` repeatedly.

```
import serial, os

ttys = os.listdir("/dev")
for tty in ttys:
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial("/dev/" + tty, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.05)  #defines the USB port
        income_value = ser.readline()
        print(income_value)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: That doesn't sound at all compliant with any USB protocol.

Comment: Try using LuaMacros: http://www.hidmacros.eu/

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I don't think it is, but I'm just asking if it's possible to read the signal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple USB button using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766167/simple-usb-button-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Serial, here are few code lines you can use :

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)  #defines the USB port
income_value = ser.readline().decode('ascii')  #read the USB value
ser.write(send_value.encode('ascii'))  #send value to USB
```

When you click on your button, you should get a signal coming from your USB port.

Comment: It gives the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'COM5'` (I have Linux, that might be the problem.)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, 'COMn' is only for Windows. Check this link out, a StackExchange user already asked for Linux: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144735)

Comment: It doesn't display the USB device, probably because it has no serial interface, since it's literally a button. Is there a way to guess-and-check different names?

Comment: Serial is just a Python module that reads what a USB port receives. So it should work. On Linux, the USB port's name should look like this : 1014:003E (you can't guess it)

To identify the name of the USB port concerned by the button, try to check this out : 
[link](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB) or this : [link](https://www.linux.org/threads/usb-port-management.22273/) they show screenshots of your computer settings so it might help you.

Comment: I have 98 `/dev/ttyX` devices, so I guess I'll check them all.

Comment: I hope you will find out the port's name... If my answer satisfies you, you can validate it.

Comment: I couldn't find the device.